# PODs and VPtr Design in C++ Compilers

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, language-design, vtable

**This question is more about language design and less about changing C++ conventions.**

While thinking about the Go programming language (how it cleaning separates the data from the interfaces, effectively turning all objects into structs) and PODs in C++ (I like memset/memcpy when allocating a gazillion small struct-like objects), I was wondering about the **C++ compiler convention of attaching a vptr directly to an instance of an object**, messing up the layout.

Is this a requirement or just a convention?

**If you were designing an alternative compiler, could you, instead, have a large external look-up table for vptrs?**  For example, a structure like **`map<void*,vptr>`**?  All instances would be POD, with respect to memory setting, and to look up its vptr, we would take its address and look inside the large external lookup table.

The disadvantage is, everything would require a lookup.  Is this a viable alternative design or are there serious drawbacks?

Comment: If you're in charge of the compiler, what's the real problem with memcpy'ing a `vptr`? It works quite well. The *real* problem is that a derived class may be bigger, and `memcpy` happily slices objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance will very probably suffer. Some languages add some kind of caching for method lookup.

You could have a different way of finding the method to call for a given selector (or method name). Look at [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) or [Self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_%28programming_language%29) or [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) or [Common Lisp Object system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System) or [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html)

However, some languages implementation contains clever tricks (caching, JIT, ...) making them as fast as C++ (but it is an implementation issue, not a language design issue).

Comment: +1 for pointing out various dispatch methods in other languages

Answer (score 2):

That map would have to store those `void*` pointers that are likely size of `vptr`, so there's actually more memory used, since `vptr`s will have to be stored just as well. And map lookup is not trivial - if there's a collision you have to perform linear search until the exact match is found. So lookups will be slower on average and more memory will be used.

Actually prepending an object with `vptr` doesn't mess the layout - subobjects are laid out exactly as without a `vptr`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have to have a v-table, although that is the route all major compilers have taken.

You don't get a vtable pointer unless you have virtual methods. If you don't want one then don't use virtual. If you only want POD then use C.

> If you were designing an alternative compiler, could you, instead, have a large external look-up table for vptrs? For example, a structure like map? All instances would be POD, with respect to memory setting, and to look up its vptr, we would take its address and look inside the large external lookup table.

What does this solve? `memset` still wouldn't work correctly - it breaks references by getting around copy methods. It also doesn't solve dynamic dispatch, for `memset` wouldn't register the type with the map.

Answer (score 0):

> All instances would be POD

There is a gross misunderstanding here.

There is a very significant difference between a class with virtual methods and a non-POD: copy constructors exist for a reason.

Simple example (simplified):

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr {
public:
  unique_ptr(): _ptr(nullptr) {}
  explicit unique_ptr(T* p): _ptr(p) {}

  unique_ptr(unique_ptr const&) = delete;
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& other): _ptr(other._ptr) { other._ptr = 0; }

  unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr other) {
    std::swap(_ptr, other._ptr);
    return *this;
  }

  ~unique_ptr() { delete _ptr; }

  T& operator*() const { return *_ptr; }
  T* operator->() const { return _ptr; }

private:
  T* _ptr;
}; // class unique_ptr<T>
```

This class is a POD in terms of layout. However a `memcpy` would be a blatant violation of the terms of use and lead to undefined behavior: the copy constructor is deleted for a reason!

Yet, no virtual method.

Any class that *owns* memory, whether directly or indirectly, is a non-POD. Given the number of classes in real usage which embeds a `std::string`... it's a rather common scenario.

*What about Go then ? There is a Garbage Collector...*

Now, it does not mean that classes should be built with virtual methods (and thus virtual pointers), but it certainly simpler to do so. I am personally a fan of Shims, however there are memory ownership/objects lifetime issues that spring up there.

Comment: virtual makes a class non-POD, but just because a class is non-virtual doesn't necessarily make it POD.  Nontheless, PODs are actually very useful for the lowest level primitive type objects (as long as we don't do anything blatantly boneheaded with them).

Comment: by definition, a POD is amenable to memcpy(), memset() http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#PODs

Comment: @kfmfe04: You said *All instances would be POD* (I added the citation in my answer). My point was thus exactly that *just because a class is non-virtual doesn't necessarily make it POD*, and so I don't quite see why you bring up these two concepts together.